# Revert a GameObject to a previous version

Tags: unity, scene

Is there a way to use an old version of a scene.unity file to revert changes for specific GameObjects only?

Occasionally Unity GameObjects can lose all their references in the Inspector (If a prefab instance, it keeps the prefabs defaults).  I have the missing references committed in my previous git commit, and have not changed any scripts on that GameObjects.

If I discard all my working changes to my scene.unity file I get my inspector references back OK.

But is there a script or process which allows you to revert specific gameobjects only to HEAD.
This would be useful when GameObjects lose their settings, and also when you want to revert only parts of your scene.

Comment: Right-clicking the inspector tab and selecting "debug" allows you to get the "Local Identifier In File" for a specific GameObject, but the trick is understanding the .unity file enough to pick the correct lines to revert..

Comment: ...assuming that both scene files are in ascii!

Comment: @Draco18s Yep, EditorSettings>AssetSerialization is set to ForceText!

Comment: [UnityYAMLSmartMerge](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/SmartMerge.html) sometimes works in this situation.